# Plot a line in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to plot the projected line between two data class. Is there alternative solution to **Plot** a line instead of using quiver?, could you assist me with that?
Thanks in advance.

```
w =[20.4327 -27.3558]'
auxw= w/norm(w);
quiver(0,0,auxw(1),auxw(2))
```

Comment: to ask another question, you can post new question or write question as comment to answer here. You shouldn't ask questions, editing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot a line use `plot`, since you want to plot a line from `[0 0]` to `auxw` do:

```
plot([0 auxw(1)], [0 auxw(2)])
```